# Unable to import ontology with Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm trying to load an earlier version of ontology in Protege that I created earlier. However, I get the following error using the TutleOntologyParser (I saved the ontology as a Turtle file):

```
uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <PNAME_LN> ":isNotGivenCombo "" at line 38, column 1.
Was expecting:
    "." ...
```

Opening in a text editor, this is what I have from lines 36-40:

```
###  http://purl.org/net/ontologyName/isNotGivenCombo

:isNotGivenCombo rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;

                           rdfs:subPropertyOf :isNotGiven .
```

The other parsers throw different errors. What is causing this issue? How can I resolve it?

This is the complete stack trace:

uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered "  ":isNotGivenCombo "" at line 38, column 1.
Was expecting:
    "." ...

```
Full Stack Trace
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.TurtleParserException: uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <PNAME_LN> ":isNotGivenCombo "" at line 38, column 1.
Was expecting:
    "." ...

    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.TurtleOntologyParser.parse(TurtleOntologyParser.java:129)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.ParsableOWLOntologyFactory.loadOWLOntology(ParsableOWLOntologyFactory.java:216)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:868)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:797)
    at org.protege.editor.owl.model.OWLModelManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromPhysicalURI(OWLModelManagerImpl.java:298)
    at org.protege.editor.owl.OWLEditorKit.handleLoadFrom(OWLEditorKit.java:207)
    at org.protege.editor.owl.OWLEditorKit.handleLoadRequest(OWLEditorKit.java:201)
    at org.protege.editor.core.ui.action.OpenAction.openInCurrentWorkspace(OpenAction.java:65)
    at org.protege.editor.core.ui.util.UIUtil.openRequest(UIUtil.java:227)
    at org.protege.editor.core.ui.action.OpenAction.actionPerformed(OpenAction.java:33)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <PNAME_LN> ":isNotGivenCombo "" at line 38, column 1.
Was expecting:
    "." ...

    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.TurtleParser.generateParseException(TurtleParser.java:1968)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.TurtleParser.jj_consume_token(TurtleParser.java:1829)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.TurtleParser.parseDocument(TurtleParser.java:107)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.turtle.parser.TurtleOntologyParser.parse(TurtleOntologyParser.java:121)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Can you share the lines from the beginning of the file to line 38? It's hard to replicate otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem. I had my base uri ending with `/` while the URIs generated with Protege for domains and ranges were starting with `#`. As a result, some of the URIs being formed had `/#` which is not permitted. For example:

```
www.example.com/#somedomain
```

To correct the error, I replaced all `:#` with `:` and set the base uri to end with `#` i.e., `www.example.com#`.